# マウスストーカーの効果を失わずに、メッセージ内容を切り替える方法

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、"文字マウスストーカー"のメッセージ内容を
selectのoptionタグで変えようとしたものですが、メッセージ自体は
切り替わるのですが、マウスストーカーの効果が失われてしまいます。
この効果が失われないでメッセージ内容を変えるには、どうすればいいでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=Shift_JIS">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>文字マウスストーカー</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
#myText {
font-style: italic;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
color: #ff0000;
position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;}
#myText div {position: relative;}
#myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}
//-->
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function message(opt){
　　　　　　document.getElementById('myText').innerHTML= opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
}
;(function(){
var msg="ご入学おめでとう！";
var size = 24;
var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;
var letter_spacing = 5;
var diameter = 10;
var speed = 0.3;
var rotation = 0.4;
if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;

msg = msg.split('');
var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

mouse = function(e){
 e = e || window.event;
 ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
 xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
},

makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning
 if(init.nopy){
  o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
  o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
 };
 currStep -= rotation;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
  d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
  d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
  d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
 };
},

drag = function(){ // makes the resistance
 y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
 x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;
 for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
  y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
  x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
 };
 makecircle();
},

init = function(){ // appends message divs, & sets initial values for positioning arrays
 if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
  ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
  xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 } else init.nopy = true;
 for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
  d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
  d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
  d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
  oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
 };
 o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
 setInterval(drag, 25);
},

ascroll = function(){
 ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
 xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
 window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
};

o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

if (window.addEventListener){
 window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
 document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
 document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);
  if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
   window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent){
 window.attachEvent('onload', init);
 document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
};
})();

// -->
</script>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ccffff">
<div style="text-align:center">
<select onchange="message(this)">
<option style="background-color:lightskyblue;font-weight:bold" value="ご入学おめでとう！" selected>メッセージ１</option>
<option style="background-color:yellow;font-weight:bold" value="誕生日おめでとう！">メッセージ２</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メッセージ同士の文字数が同じなので、各要素の中身を変えてやるだけでよいと思います。

```
function message(opt) {
    var t = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;
    for(var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).innerHTML = t.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

文字数の増減を伴う処理の場合、`(function(){ ... })()`内のローカル変数を操作する必要があるためこの設計では無理があります。ですので該当部分の関数を消してグローバルに変えてやります。

```
// ;(function(){
中略
// })();
```

こうすると弊害として`return`が使えなくなります。ここは`throw`に変えるか、行自体をコメントアウトすればよいと思います。

```
if (!window.addEventListener
    && !window.attachEvent
    || !document.createElement)
    throw 'error';
```

上の三か所を変えれば`function message(opt)`から変数にアクセスできますので、以下のような処理が実装できます。

```
function message(opt)
{
    var currentLength = msg.length;
    var t = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex].value;

    // 状態の変更
    msg = t.split('');
    n = msg.length - 1;

    // 文字要素の変更
    for (var i = Math.max(currentLength, msg.length) - 1; i > -1; --i)
    {
        var d = i < currentLength ? document.getElementById('iemsg' + i) : null;
        if (d)
        {
            if (i < t.length)
            {
                // 既存要素の内容変更
                d.innerHTML = msg[i];
            }
            else
            {
                // 不要になった要素の削除
                d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // 不足要素の追加
            d = document.createElement('div');
            d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
            d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
            oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
optionのvalueの値が大元のメッセージ数より少ない場合は、途中から文字が追加されますので、値のメッセージ数を合わせなければなりませんが、これで間に合います。
onchangeイベントハンドラーから状態変数を参照できる構成にしようとした方が応用が利きますので試したのですが、知識不足のためにうまくいきません。
どのように構成すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 希望通りに行きました。奇妙な形の”(function(){ ... })()”は、プロでは常識の形かと思いますが、即時関数と言うのですね。javulascriptは、本当に奥深いです。

Comment: @user9359 初期化で即時関数を使うのはライブラリ的な作法なので、最初はあまり気にしなくてよいと思います。それよりオブジェクト指向な設計を導入したほうが良いですよ。特に文字単位のデータは現時点で配列が4個もあるので、これを「プロトタイプ」を使った実装にすると機能追加しやすくなるんじゃないかと思います。